# Filter subdirectories based on regex in java

Tags: java, regex, java-8, java-io

I have a directory structure as below:

```
/test_directory/data/date=2021-01-01/
/test_directory/data/date=2021-01-02/
/test_directory/data/date=2021-01-03/
/test_directory/data/sample=2021-01-04/
/test_directory/data/sample=2021-01-05/
```

I want to filter only the date folders.

```
/test_directory/data/date=2021-01-01/
/test_directory/data/date=2021-01-02/
/test_directory/data/date=2021-01-03/
```

I tired the below code: But unable to keep the regex in the directory path.

```
String dir = "/test_directory/data/";
File[] directories = new File(dir).listFiles(File::isDirectory);
for(int i=0;i< directories.length;i++){
    System.out.println(directories[i]);
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? Otherwise you could simply do something like `directory.getName().startsWith("date")`.

Comment: But it is returning the boolean value.

Comment: The example I gave before is not meant to be a full solution, since it is only a comment, not an answer. Now, back to my question: Does it have to be a regex?

Comment: No need to regex only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let's migrate to the `nio` API, which is meant to replace the `File` API since Java 1.7.

```
String dir = "/test_directory/data/";
Files.list(Paths.get(dir))
    .filter(Files::isDirectory)
    .forEach(directory -> {
        System.out.println(directory.toString());
    };
```

At this point, since you have a `Stream`, you can easily add an additional filter. This can be regex-based or just a simple `String.startsWith`.

```
String dir = "/test_directory/data/";
Files.list(Paths.get(dir))
    .filter(Files::isDirectory)
    .filter(directory -> directory.getFileName().toString().startsWith("date"))
    .forEach(directory -> {
        System.out.println(directory.toString());
    };
```

---

Using the `File` API, you cannot have multiple filters, so you have to combine yourself.

```
String dir = "/test_directory/data/";
File[] directories = new File(dir).listFiles(
    directory -> directory.isDirectory()
 && directory.getName().startsWith("date"));
for (File directory : directories) {
    System.out.println(directory.getPath());
}
```